# Calling several functions using JavaScript's window.onload attribute

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I have the following code in the index.html page of my site, which when the page loads, draws a number of images to the HTML5 canvas:

```
window.onload = function(){



    var sources = {};
        sources[0] = document.getElementById("building").src,
        sources[1] = document.getElementById("chair").src,
        sources[2] = document.getElementById("drink").src,
        sources[3] = document.getElementById("food").src,
        sources[4] = document.getElementById("fridge").src,
        sources[5] = document.getElementById("land").src,
        sources[6] = document.getElementById("money").src,
        sources[7] = document.getElementById("oven").src,
        sources[8] = document.getElementById("table").src,
        sources[9] = document.getElementById("van").src,

        sources[10] = document.getElementById("burger").src,
        sources[11] = document.getElementById("chips").src,
        sources[12] = document.getElementById("drink").src,
        sources[13] = document.getElementById("franchiseFee").src,
        sources[14] = document.getElementById("wages").src,

        sources[15] = document.getElementById("admin").src,
        sources[16] = document.getElementById("cleaners").src,
        sources[17] = document.getElementById("electricity").src,
        sources[18] = document.getElementById("insurance").src,
        sources[19] = document.getElementById("manager").src,
        sources[20] = document.getElementById("rates").src,
        sources[21] = document.getElementById("training").src,
        sources[22] = document.getElementById("water").src,

        sources[23] = document.getElementById("burger").src,
        sources[24] = document.getElementById("chips").src,
        sources[25] = document.getElementById("drink").src,

        sources[26] = document.getElementById("creditors").src,
        sources[27] = document.getElementById("electricity").src,
        sources[28] = document.getElementById("food").src,
        sources[29] = document.getElementById("hirePurchase").src,
        sources[30] = document.getElementById("loan").src,
        sources[31] = document.getElementById("overdraft").src,
        sources[32] = document.getElementById("payeTax").src,
        sources[33] = document.getElementById("tax").src

    loadImages(sources, drawImage);
};
```

Sources is the array that I'm using to hold the images in JavaScript so that they can be drawn to the canvas once they've been loaded from a hidden section in my HTML.

This function currently works exactly as it's intended- it has a call to the loadImages function, which loads the images from a hidden section in the HTML into the JavaScript array, and calls the `drawImage` function on each of the images in the array.
But I also have another function that I want to be called with the window.onload:

The function I want to add to window.onload is this:

```
function drawGameElements(){
    /* Draw a line for the 'score bar'. */
    context.moveTo(0, 25);
    context.lineTo(1000, 25);
    context.stroke();

    /* Draw current level/ total levels on the left, and current score on the right. */
    context.font = "11pt Calibri"; /* Text font & size */
    context.strokeStyle = "black"; /* Font colour */
    context.strokeText(currentLevel + "/" + totalLevels, 10, 15);
    context.strokeText(currentScore, 950, 15);
}
```

I tried adding a call to the function just below the `loadImages(sources, drawImage);` line in `window.onload = function(){};`

So that I now have:

```
window.onload = function(){
...
loadImages(sources, drawImage);
drawGameElements();
};
```

Although this partially works, in that it draws the line across the top of the canvas for the 'score bar' and writes "1/3" for the levels on the left hand side of the canvas just above the line, for some reason it doesn't draw the current score on the right hand side.

Also, as soon as I click on one of the images that's been drawn to the canvas, to drag and drop it around the canvas, the 'score bar' then disappears from the canvas completely.

Does anyone know why this is? How can I get the score bar to remain visible throughout the duration of the game, no matter what else happens on the canvas? Also, how can I get the currentScore variable to be displayed?

Answer (score 0):

I would instead use a callback inside of loadImages to call drawGameElements. That way drawGameElements only runs after loadImages is finished. It sounds like you've created a race condition with your two functions.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, that would mean putting the call to `drawGameElements();` at the end of my `loadImages()` function, instead of at the end of `window.onload = function... ` ?

Comment: Having given that a try, I still have the same problems as described in my original question, although I think this is probably better for code clarity. Do you know how I can stop the score bar from disappearing when an image is clicked? Or how to get the current score displaying in the same way as the current level does?

Comment: That's likely going to be an issue with CSS. I would try what Wutz has said and use position:aboslute; on the score bar to see if that helps. We'd need to see more of your code to figure out what's going on with the score bar. Maybe try putting up the bare minimum on jsfiddle.com.

Comment: I've not actually used any CSS on my page as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 0):

If I where you, I would create the score bar outside of the canvas. Set its position to absolute and let it hover above the canvas at the desired location. That way you can just access it as HTML elements and do not need to worry about redrawing.

The major advantage of using HTML elements for these displays is that you don't need to redraw them, for example after moving the images around on the canvas. You also don't have to worry about how to refresh the values (on a canvas, just painting new values over the old ones will not be enough). This way you can just store the values in HTML elements and go wild on the canvas, knowing the score will always stay on top.

Comment: I have created the score bar outside the canvas (I've used a separate JS function to write it), however, I want it to be displayed on the canvas, as part of the canvas, as this is neater than placing it over the top... I can't be sure that it would display where I want it to if it's just 'on top' of the canvas, as different browsers may interpret it differently, screen resolution may affect it, etc.

Comment: I do have to worry about refreshing the values- as the score will increase during the play of the game/ user will progress to the next level, etc. So I will have a function to clear everything on the canvas, and redraw the elements as and when required

Comment: If you put a container around the canvas and set that to position relative you can put the score bar exactly where you want it to be, regardless of the browser, because it will be positioned inside that container (thus: relative to the canvas). Also, I know you have to refresh the values, all I am saying is that you can avoid a total redraw of the canvas.